# Sqlalchemy overwrite data in table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have problem . This code overwrite data in tables. I would like add rows into existing tables and without deleting existing rows.

```
class Ordering(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = 'ordering'
    id_z = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    family = Column(String(100), nullable=False)
    name = Column(String(100), nullable=False)
    phone = Column(String(15), nullable=False)
    id_m = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('menu.id_m'))


class Menu(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = 'menu'
    id_m = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    dish = Column(String(100), nullable=False)
    quantity = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    measurment = Column(String(10), nullable=False)
    relation = relationship('Ordering', backref='Menu')


BaseModel.metadata.create_all(base)
while True:
    BDSesion = sessionmaker(bind=base)
    session = BDSesion()
    if not session.query(Menu).count():
      session.add(Menu(dish=input('dish'), quantity=input('quantity'),measurment=input('measurment')))

    n = input("Please enter 'q' to finish any other key next:")
    if n.upper().strip() == 'Q':
        session.commit()
        session.close()
        break
```

Comment: A new session is created in each iteration of the while loop, so only the final session's contents are inserted. Session creation should be outside the loop. Additionally, the check on `session,query(Menu).count()` will prevent additional instances being added after the first.

Answer (score -1):

I use pandas to read in data and can append to a table like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy
import urllib

cs = 'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=' + server + ';Trusted_Connection=no;uid=' + uid + ';pwd=' + pwd + ';'

params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(cs)

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params)

df.to_sql('tablename', engine, schema='schema_name', index=False, if_exists='append')
```